# Dataframe query result to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To get a plain string from a dataframe query, I use:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "value": [1,2,3],
})

df.query("value == 1")['name'].tolist()[0]

# 'a'
```

Just wondering if this is the right way to process a `pandas.core.series.Series` object (i.e. whether there is a more Pythonic way of doing this).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is correct, if value exist.

If possible not exist here is `next` + `iter` trick:

```
out = next(iter(df.query("value == 1")['name']), 'no match')

out = next(iter(df.loc[df["value"] == 1, 'name']), 'no match')
```